# Странность с binding wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть разметка XAML:

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="PathListView"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
    Margin="5"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SettingModel.CollectionPaths, Mode=Default}" />
```

Так вот, в этом случае связывание не срабатывает - отображаемый элемент - пустой. А вот если это сделать в c# коде и убрать с XAML - вуаля, все работает:

```
PathListView.ItemsSource = ViewModel.MainViewModel.SettingModel.CollectionPaths;
```

В чем разница между тем, как привязывать, в xaml или c# коде?
 Почему в одном случае работает, а в другом - нет?
Обе коллекции *ObservableCollection<>*

**UPD**.
 Код модели:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace DocumentAdder.Model
{
[DataContract]
public class SettingsModel : BaseModel
{
    #region Fields
    private string _pathToDirectory;
    private string _fileTypes;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _collectionPaths;
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Представляет собой путь к папке с файлами, которые следует обработать
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>PathToDirectory свойство задает/возвращает значение типа string поля, _pathToDirectory</value>
    [DataMember]
    public string PathToDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            return _pathToDirectory;
        }
        set
        {
            _pathToDirectory = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Предоставляет данные о типах текстовых файлов, которые необходимо сканировать и обрабатывать
    /// <value>FileTypes свойство возвращает значения типа string поля, _fileTypes</value>
    /// </summary>       
    [DataMember]
    public string FileTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileTypes;
        }
        private set
        {
            _fileTypes = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает коллекцию всех путей, с которых нужно обработать файлы
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>CollectionPaths свойство возвращает значение типа ObservableCollection<string> поля, _collectionPaths</value>
    [DataMember]
    public ObservableCollection<string> CollectionPaths
    {
        get
        {
            return _collectionPaths;
        }
        private set
        {
            _collectionPaths = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Создает модель настроек, 
    /// инициализирует коллекцию путей к директориям, где лежат файлы,
    /// задает возможные форматы файлов для чтения.
    /// </summary>
    public SettingsModel()
    {
        _fileTypes = "*.txt, *.doc, *.docx, *.rtf, *.otd, *.pdf";
        CollectionPaths = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
}
```

Код ViewModel:

```
using DocumentAdder.Helpers;
using DocumentAdder.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

namespace DocumentAdder.ViewModel
{
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainModel DocumentAdderModel { get; private set; }
    public static SettingsModel SettingModel { get; set; }

    #region Commands
    //main programm commands
    public ICommand StartProgrammCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand StopProgrammCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand RestartProgrammCommand { get; private set; }

    //settings commands
    public ICommand AddLocalStorageCommand { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    //main programm methods

    //settings methods
    private void addLocalStorage()
    {
        List<string> selectedPaths = null;
        var cofd = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        cofd.IsFolderPicker = true;
        //cofd.Title = "";
        cofd.Multiselect = true;
        if (cofd.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            selectedPaths = cofd.FileNames.ToList<string>();
        }
        if (selectedPaths != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in selectedPaths)
            {
                SettingModel.CollectionPaths.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addFTPStorage()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    static MainViewModel()
    {
        if (SettingModel == null)
        {
            var single = new SettingsModel();
            SettingModel = single;
        }            
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DocumentAdderModel = new MainModel();
        AddLocalStorageCommand = new DelegateCommand(arg => addLocalStorage());
    }
}
}
```

Код XAML окна:

```
<Window
x:Class="DocumentAdder.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:PlatformUI="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocumentAdder"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DocumentAdder.ViewModel"
Title="Document Adder"
Width="535"
Height="340"
Closing="Window_Closing"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TabControl
        x:Name="tabControl"
        Width="500"
        Height="282"
        Margin="10,10,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="Стартовая">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DataGrid
                    x:Name="fileDataView"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Width="474"
                    Margin="10,10,0,38"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Width="40"
                            CanUserResize="False"
                            CanUserSort="True"
                            Header="#"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Width="200"
                            CanUserResize="True"
                            CanUserSort="False"
                            Header="Путь к файлу"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Тип файла" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Width="110"
                            CanUserResize="False"
                            CanUserSort="True"
                            Header="Дата добавления"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="В БД?" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                <Button
                    x:Name="StartBtn"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Width="75"
                    Margin="10,61,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Content="Start" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="StopBtn"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Width="75"
                    Margin="90,61,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Content="Stop" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="RestartBtn"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Width="75"
                    Margin="170,61,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Content="Restart" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Настройки">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListBox
                    x:Name="PathListView"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                    Margin="5" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button
                        Height="28"
                        Margin="10,10,10,0"
                        Command="{Binding AddLocalStorageCommand}"
                        Content="Добавить путь" />
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="О программе">
            <TextBlock><Run Text="Добавление и фильтрация данных" /></TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

[Весь проект](https://yadi.sk/d/Q6Fj83uVz8WHm)

Comment: А можете описать подробнее, в частности переходы между вашими UI , может не успевает обновиться?

Comment: покажите как вы устанавливаете DataContext окна где находится ваш ListBox

Comment: @FoggyFinder DataContext установлен, остальные привязки работют.

Comment: @YuryBakharev, а нету других окон, есть TabControl, на другой вкладке этот ListBox. Привязка команды к кнопке работает через xaml, а вот это - нет.

Comment: А что пишет Visual Studio про ошибки привязки в окне Output? Там часто бывает полезная информация.

Comment: @FoggyFinder добавил код

Comment: @VladD vs молчит, как будто все ок.

Comment: Попробуйте `ItemsSource="{x:Static vm:MainViewModel.SettingModel.CollectionPaths}`

Comment: @Vlad выдает ошибку "Вложенные типы не поддерживаются: MainViewModel.SettingModel"

Comment: Ok, тогда так `ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPaths, Source={x:Static vm:MainViewModel.SettingModel}}"`

Comment: @Vlad ошибки нет, но привязка не работает все равно ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder остальная часть все равно не участвует в работе окна. Попробую установить, что вы сказали.

Comment: А у вас в коллекции точно элементы есть? Попробуйте положить хотя бы один элемент в коллекцию (прямо в конструкторе) и посмотреть, выводится ли он?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попытался составить минимально воспроизводимый пример. Просьба к автору поправить, если я неверно понял задачу.

Есть нестатический класс с нестатическим свойством-коллекцией:

```
public class Model
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; }

    public Model()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    } 
}
```

Есть модель представления окна, в которой данный класс фигурирует в виде статического свойства и которая умеет добавлять элементы в коллекцию:

```
public class MainVm
{
    private int currentItem;

    public static Model Model { get; }

    static MainVm()
    {
        if (Model == null)
        {
            Model = new Model();
        }
    }

    public MainVm()
    {
        AddItemToCollectionCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Model.Collection.Add((++currentItem).ToString()));
    }

    public ICommand AddItemToCollectionCommand { get; }
}
```

Есть представление, которое должно показывать перечень элементов коллекции в ListBox:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddItemToCollectionCommand}" Content="Add"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Source={x:Static local:MainVm.Model}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Если организовать привязку таким образом, то код будет работать.

**UPD**

@Ep1demic, во-первых, в привязке не `Collection`, а `CollectionPaths`. Во-вторых, проблема в том, что вы заново устанавливаете значение статического свойства. Т.е. получается следующее:

1. Создали класс `MainViewModel`.
2. Отработал Binding к `SettingModel.CollectionPaths` (т.е. к значению созданному в статическом конструкторе).
3. Значение свойства `SettingModel` изменилось.

В итоге привязка работает, но к пустой коллекции. Так что вам нужно что-то с этим придумать. Либо найти способ оповещать внешний код об изменении статического свойства, либо избавиться от статики, либо не менять значение свойства.

Comment: Должно, но не работает ;) Ну не знаю уж. Закинул проект на ядиск, если кто-то хочет - поковыряйтесь.

Comment: @Ep1demic, обновил ответ